# Server File through scp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multi-server setup. Picture a client, a web server running rails, and a instance that stores data. I need a way to access the data store files from the client through the webserver.

Currently I am using scp to download the files to the web server in a temp directory then redirect the client to the tmp url.

I would much prefer to be able to stream the file through the web server without storing them.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative approach would be to use sshfs and mount the remote server (readonly)

```
sshfs -o ro server:/path/to/files path/on/webserver/to/mount
```

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/

---

In terms of streaming via your question:

You could do something like this:

```
data = `ssh server 'cat path/to/file/on/server'`
send_data(data)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data

---

The trick here is to use ssh instead of scp,  try it out from your shell

```
ssh server 'cat path/to/file' > local_file
```

This allows you to send the file to STDOUT locally (it cannot be done via scp.)

---

This allows you to stream the file but I don't recommend doing this.

1. You're loading the file into Ruby which will needlessly bloat your process.
2. You lose the benefits of X-Sendfile to offload the download outside of your rails process
3. **If the path includes user supplied data, you introduce yourself (and the server) to a world of hurt via shell injection.**